# "error: cannot find symbol variable xml" while trying google analytics

Tags: java, android, xml, google-analytics

I am trying to implement google analytics for one of my android apps. I am totally new for analytics and android app development. I thought of trying the examples given in the google developers site. When trying to compile their code, I am getting the error pointing the analytics application java file, `mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);` line, .xml is highlighted. I posted the whole code here.

This is AnalyticsApplication.java

```
package com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics;

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
  private Tracker mTracker;

  synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
      mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
  }
}
```

My Global_tracker.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-X</string>

    <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have already spent two complete days in this issue, and I need your suggestion to go forwards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create a new folder in your res folder called `xml` and move your file to that folder. Also make sure you call the layout name correctly because in your question, you wrote `Global_tracker.xml` instead of `global_tracker.xml`. This is so important.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. that saved me.

Comment: What layout you are talking about? global_tracking.xml is an xml resource file that should be generated by GoogleAnalytics gradle plugin.

Comment: @Luten It is just a values resource file that the asker created somewhere else rather than xml folder as the title clearly states, and the asker didn't know that he should create a new folder called xml to fix this problem. So he should definitely create it.

Comment: 1. Your answer says about layout files, which is confusing as there are no layout files. Also layout files should not be placed in xml folder.
2. This is not the right way you should work with google analytics.
global_tracker.xml file is generated automatically, and should not be created manually.
The asker;s problem is caused by broken autogeneration. Discussion and workarounds about this problem may be found here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/26

Comment: @Luten You're right about me writing layout files. It was a mistake from me, and I fixed it yesterday. Anyway, this solution solved the asker's issue. Moreover, global_tracker.xml is not a layout file; it is a values resource file. Also it should not be auto-generated as the asker is required to input his tracking id in a resource file.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky Edited your answer too. Removed downvote. As I already wrote - this file is generated automatically by Google Analytics gradle plugin. Asker is not required to input tracking id, it's just autogeneration error.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you don't forget to put

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

in app level build.gradle

Comment: at the end of the file

Comment: For me it works even in module-level build.gradle, after applying application plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The **brute force** solution is to simply provide the actual analytics code.

```java
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Tracker tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-XXXXXXXXX-X");
```

rather than following the android conventional procedure

```java
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Tracker tracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
```

It's a pretty savage way of fixing the issue but it surely works because the [newTracker()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#newTracker(java.lang.String)) method only needs the actual **string** value of the Google Analytics tracking code.

The [official reference document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics) even have the same paradigm example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when was preforming downgrade to lower version from

```
com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0
```

to

```
com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.1
```

*(Do not ask why(it was an assumption in order to fix CI build script in a hurry))*

So, make sure that you did not made downgrade changes

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue with play service library version 10.2.1 for gcm and google analytics and issue is simply fixed by adding **global_tracker.xml** as discussed in the **@Hussein El Feky** Answer but only that fix is not solved my issue also i've added two more lines in **strings.xml**:

```
<string name="global_tracker">UA-XXXXXXXX-XX</string>
<string name="gcm_defaultSenderId">PROJECT-NO</string>
```

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the similar issue.

Use classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3`. That solved my problem.