# Android studio - Cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've added an XML file `app_tracker.xml` under the `res\xml` directory, but it seems that Android Studio cannot find it.

I've rebuilt and synced Gradle multiple times, but it did not work.
How can I resolve that?

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import android.R;
import android.R.xml;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by David on 12-Mar-16.
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    // The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-75038910-1";

    //Logging TAG
    private static final String TAG = "WiggleTasks";

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public MyApplication() {
        super();
    }

    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId)
    {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId))
        {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = null;
            if(trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER)
            {
                t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
            }
            else if(trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER)
            {
                t = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
            }

            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

Another issue came up. I'm suddenly getting the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class
```

What can be the reason?

**Gradle File**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
}
```

Comment: under res/layout? remove the .R from the import and press alt enter and see if solves

Comment: Please check the recent modifications made in your xml. There may be some errors. This "R cannot be resolved" error happens because of that.

Comment: @JMR, the directory is 'main\res\xml', should I still remove the .R?

Comment: @MidhunVijayakumar, no modifications were made, the file is new.

Comment: try and tell if it solves.

Comment: I never heard of xml directory in resources it should be layout , menu or values

Comment: @meda It's valid. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.xml.html

Comment: @DavidFaiz If you defined the value yourself, then why are you importing  `android.R`? Those are values defined by the SDK, not your project under `main/res`

Comment: @JMR, tried it, did not work.

Comment: @cricket_007, removed the imports and still get the error.

Comment: @meda, I followed a tutorial about utilizing Google analytics, and they requested to add 'xml' directory under RES.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078992/error-cannot-find-symbol-variable-xml-while-trying-google-analytics) helps. There is also, a [Github issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/26) that seems related.

Comment: @cricket_007, after a few more clean & rebuild, it was resolved.
Thank you!

Comment: @cricket_007, another issue came up.
I'm suddenly getting the following error 'Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class'

What can be the reason?

Comment: You are compiling something more than once in your Gradle file.

Comment: @cricket_007, I added the Gradle file, I do not see any duplicate entries.

Comment: Do you have any jars in the libs folder?

Comment: @cricket_007, only 'picasso-2.3.4.jar'.

Comment: You can get the latest Picasso in your Gradle with `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`, but I don't know what to tell you. That error only happens when there are "overlapping" class files in your dependencies. I can see the project is ObjectWeb ASM based on the package name of the class, but I don't know which library you included uses that class.

Comment: @cricket_007, the issue was self-resolved. Probably an IDE issue.
In any case, I'm facing another issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963708/google-analytics-string-xml-configuration-name-not-recognized
Can you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the file `main\res\xml\app_tracker.xml` setup correctly without any errors.

Remove these lines because they are for the Android SDK resource values, not your app.

```
import android.R;
import android.R.xml;
```

Then try to clean and rebuild.