# Google analytics - 'String xml configuration name not recognized'

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm attempting to utilize Google Analytics in my app and encountering a few issues. Upon running the app I get the following logcat messages:

```
03-12 23:27:11.107 25448-25448/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 W/GAv4: String xml configuration name not recognized: il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.MainActivity
03-12 23:27:11.111 25448-25448/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 W/GAv4: String xml configuration name not recognized: il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.EditTaskActivity
03-12 23:27:11.111 25448-25448/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 W/GAv4: String xml configuration name not recognized: il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.ReportTaskStatus
03-12 23:27:11.119 25448-25448/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 W/GAv4: AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled. Register the receiver for reliable dispatching on non-Google Play devices. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
03-12 23:27:11.120 25448-25448/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 W/GAv4: CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
03-12 23:27:11.151 25448-27033/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2 W/GAv4: AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
```

Here is my **manifest.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ListNodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_node"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Signup_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateTeam"
            android:label="Create new task team"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".InviteMember"
            android:label="Invite Members Your Team"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Login_activity"
            android:label="Login to Wiggle"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditTaskActivity"
            android:label="Edit Task"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SelectLocation"
            android:label="Select Location"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReportTaskStatus"
            android:label="Report Task Status"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Google Analytics Version v4 needs this value for easy tracking -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
            android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the **global_tracker.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<!-- the Local LogLevel for Analytics -->
<string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>

<!-- how often the dispatcher should fire -->
<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>

<!-- Treat events as test events and don't send to google -->
<bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

<!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
<string name="il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.MainActivity">Main Activity</string>
<string name="il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.EditTaskActivity">Edit Task Activity</string>
<string name="il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.ReportTaskStatus">Report Task Status Activity</string>
</resources>
```

**app_tracker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- End current session if app sleeps for a period of time -->
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!--  The property id associated with this analytics tracker -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-75038910-1</string>

    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <!--
      See Project Structure -> Analytics -> Google Analytics -> Learn More
      to learn more about configuring this file.
    -->
</resources>
```

Obviously, there are no records in my Google analytics page, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you `See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.`??

Comment: @cricket_007, I'm actually more wondering about 'String xml configuration name not recognized', or might they be related?

Comment: Not sure. Never used Google analytics. If you could provide a link to a tutorial you are following that tells you how to set it up, I'd be willing to look at it

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api

http://javatechig.com/android/integrating-google-analytics-in-android-example

Comment: Hmm, only that first link does that XML thing with the package names. Are you sure it's possible, and why do you really need it? You're just adding spaces to your class names. And those are warnings, not errors.

Comment: @cricket_007, thank you for all your help!
I removed the Parse stuff, did not notice that.

Comment: It's in the edit history now. If someone really wants it, they'll get it

Comment: @cricket_007, it's a College project, so I'm not too bothered.